# Error: gobject-introspection: uninitialized constant Language::Python::Shebang

Tags: opencv

While executing the following command:

```
brew install opencv
```

I am encountered with the following exception:

```
Error: gobject-introspection: uninitialized constant Language::Python::Shebang
```

Could you please help me find the root cause for this and resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Language::Python::Shebang is the replacement for Language::Python.rewrite_python_shebang, which was deprecated in Homebrew `2.3.0`

So you are likely using a version of Homebrew prior to `2.3.0` You can check your Homebrew version with `brew --version`.

Just doing `brew update` should update Homebrew to the latest version.

If you at some point added or changed a formula and worked locally on it you could be on a feature branch or your Homebrew working directory is changed so it does not update the `master` branch.

In these cases try the following:

- `cd /usr/local/Homebrew`
- git status
- Discard or `git stash` your changes or `git checkout master` if you are on a feature branch
- Once the working directory is clean you can `brew update` to update Homebrew